# I Want to print StudentsBio Then No ,StudentsBio Then No ,StudentsBio Then No Until loop completes

Tags: python

```
Filename=open('StudentBio.txt','w')
Name=1
fathername=1
Nationality=1
religion=1
if Name==1 and fathername==0 and Nationality==1 and religion==1:
    print('You are Eligible for Admission\nCongratualation')
else:
    print('Tick All The Above boxes That You Have To fill')
    def StudentBiography(Name,fathername,Nationality,religion):
        Name=input('Enter Name Of student : ')
        fathername=input('Enter Name Of father : ')
        Nationality=input('Enter Nationality :')
        religion=input('Enter Religion : ')
        all_info=[Name,fathername,Nationality,religion]
        return all_info
def Grading(Maths,Islamiat,English):
    A=Maths+Islamiat+English
    B=(A/300)*100
    C=[Maths,Islamiat,English]
    return (B,C)
for i in range(2):
    a=StudentBiography(Name,fathername,Nationality,religion)
    f=str(a)
    Filename.write(f)
for j in range(2):
    Maths = eval(input('Enter no : '))
    Islamiat = eval(input('Enter no : '))
    English = eval(input('Enter no : '))
    b=Grading(Maths,Islamiat,English)
    g=str(b)
    Filename.write(g)
Filename.close()
```

please Help me I need Serious Help

Comment: Please be specific about your problem, and what you hope for us to help you with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what I can understand you would like to write student information to a text file. First of all, I think you should read more about Python syntax and work on your scripting. For example in Python variables and functions should start with lowercase letters and you need spaces around `=` sign and things like that. I will try my best to help you out.

```py
def get_student_bio():
    name = input('Enter Name Of student : ')
    father_name = input('Enter Name Of father : ')
    nationality = input('Enter Nationality :')
    religion = input('Enter Religion : ')
    return ' '.join([name, father_name, nationality, religion])

def get_student_grade():
    math = input('Enter no : ')
    islamiat = input('Enter no : ')
    english = input('Enter no : ')
    avg = str(sum(float(math) + float(islamiat) + float(english)) / 3)
    return ' '.join([avg, math, islamiat, english])

fileobj = open('StudentBio.txt','w')

for i in range(2):
    bio = get_student_bio()
    grades = get_student_grades()
    fileobj.write(bio + ' ' + grades + '\n')

fileobj.close()
```

I assume you are trying to enter student bio and grades one by one and write them in a text file. Here is one way you can achieve this. I tried to keep it similar to the way you were doing it so maybe it's easier to understand. I got rid of the initial `if` statement though because I wasn't sure what you were trying to achieve with that. Anyways, hope this is useful.

Comment: Changing the style of the OP's code at this level isn't really productive.